# Redirecting to an external url but keeping my navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, href

Is it possible to redirect a user with like `href="https://calendly.com"`, but keep my navbar displayed?

Comment: You cannot control an external website after a redirect. Probably you should use something like a IFRAME, where you don't redirect the user, but show another website inside a div in your own... So you can keep elements like your navbar https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP

Comment: u can't do that with just using html and css. You have to use react and react-router.

Comment: @DarthApprentice No, you don't need ReactJS. ReactJS is not some kind of universal solution - and you can't load external content into an iframe if a CSP is set.

Comment: I tried with IFRAME but the access to the external link is blocked, I don't really know why

Comment: Well I'll try to find something else then , thanks for answering :)

Comment: @DayvinZahout You can't "find something else" - what you're asking is impossible. Why do you want to do this anyway?